# Filter off dates lesser than currentDate in VBA

Tags: vba, filter

I am trying to filter off dates in the column which have a date lesser than today. I have written the code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Sub FilterByDate()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.[c2], ws1.Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp))
Dim todayDate As Date
todayDate = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
rng1.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & todayDate
rng1.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
ws1.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

This code doesn't filter for the dates lesser than today. When I filter, the list doesn't seem to change. Need some help on this.

EDIT:

```
15/03/2016
15/12/2015
17/11/2015
14/01/2016
18/02/2016
14/04/2016
15/12/2015
17/11/2015
14/01/2016
17/11/2015
```

[image]

Comment: This is working for me. Are you sure that your column C actually contains *date* values (and not to be confused with string literals which *look like* dates)?

Comment: I have tried that as well. Ensured the datatype of these values is actually dates.

Comment: Are you using a non-US English system Locale?

Comment: ya, but changed to US English system Locale and retried, but to no avail.

Comment: Can you add some example data of the dates you are working with in column C?

Comment: sure. done. trying to filter off 17/11/2015

Comment: Try using the additional parameter `Operator:=xlAnd` on the autofilter statement, see my answer below, this seems to be working as long as ensure they are *dates* and not string/text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your `AutoFilter` statement, do:

```
Operator:=xlAnd
```

So that line shall become:

```
rng1.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & todayDate, Operator:=xlAnd
```

Must be something different about date filters where this operator is required.  I will not claim to having *known* this in advance, I used the macro recorder to figure it out :)

[image]

**Additional infos from the comments:**

Your problem may be related to system locale, and VBA's "feature" of using US English dates, internally.

- First: the dates you provide as examples are **not** valid US-English dates, and will not resolve as such (one particular fun problem with dates is that 3/6/2015 resolves as June 3 to the rest of the world, while it is March 6 in US English.  Values like 17/11/2015 are not dates at all.
- Additionally: there may be some bad juju going on in this statement:

  `todayDate = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")`

  Here, you are taking a *date* (long integer, which results from `Date()` function) and casting it to string via `Format()` which returns a string, then you're putting that string in to the `todayDate` variable.  Even if you have resolved the issue with locale settings, this statement may be problematic in its own right.

Comment: Then you do not have true dates in your column C. Perhaps they are text *formatted as date* (which is still a text/string, not a long/numeric data).  Or perhaps they are non-US date format (VBA uses US date format internally, so often require some conversion from locale).

Comment: have ensured they are dates and that they are US date format. but still not working

Comment: I am certain you are mistaken.  The example dates you provided are **not** US English format.  You are casting a date (from the `Date` function) into a string (using the `Format` function), and then casting that string in to a date variable with `todayDate = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")`  That statement may be part of your problem.

Comment: I double checked it. Change the code to todayDate = Date. sitll the problem exist. Added the image as well.

Comment: From the UI, I can see that you are simply applying a mask/format to the range of cells. This is not actually converting string to Date (which is stored as a long/integer in Excel).  So, you may not be working with dates in column C, instead you have text which is formatted to appear as a date. But it is not a date.

Comment: There is also the possible issue with system local conflicting with VBA; which I am not really in a position to solve for you. It's a terribly frustrating problem, but once you have identified it as such, I beleive there are other Q&A here on SO and elsewhere on the internet, which you can use to resolve.

Comment: its a terrible and frustating problem indeed.

Comment: If you format the range *as number*, you should see values like `42444, 
42353, 
42325, ...` If you don't see that, then at least you know where the problem resides.

Comment: When I format it as a number, I do see the numbers.

Comment: I tried something. I converted all of them to numbers and changed today date to a number as well and when compare the dates, the dates are appearing when I filter. However when I compare as dates, I don't see it.

Comment: Dates are numbers.  If you've changed it to a number, then you have successfully converted it from text --> date (which is stored in Excel as a Long/Integer type).  If you compare them "as dates" (which I presume to mean "as text which looks like a date", it will not work.  You need to be working with actual dates (long/integer), not text.